# esp8266 Does not start after firmware update

Tags: esp8266

I am updating firmware for my esp8266 from flash using following code:

```
RunBinary(const String& strFileName)
{
  Debug("Flashing binary " + strFileName);

  File file = SPIFFS.open(strFileName, "r");
  uint32_t maxSketchSpace = (ESP.getFreeSketchSpace() - 0x1000) & 0xFFFFF000;

  if (file)
  {
    if (!Update.begin(maxSketchSpace, U_FLASH))
    {
      Update.printError(Serial);
      Debug("Failed to load the task binary");
    }
    else
    {
      while (file.available())
      {
        uint8_t ibuffer[128];
        file.read((uint8_t *)ibuffer, 128);
        Update.write(ibuffer, sizeof(ibuffer));
      }

      file.close();

      if (Update.end(true))
      {
        Serial.println("Update Success" ); 
        return true;
      }
    }
  }
  else
    Serial.printf("Failed to open binary file");

  Update.printError(Serial);
  return false;
}
```

After above returns true i reboot the esp with:

```
        if (RunBinary("/Binary.bin") == true)
        {
          ESP.restart();
        }
```

It works randomly, sometimes new program starts - but most of the times it returns with some trash

```
Flashing binary /Binary.bin
Update Success
?)²
ôDHB÷^HLlÿ
```

And hangs forever.

Where to look for a cause?

```
SKETCH SIZE     : 363264
FREE SKETCH SIZE: 2781184
APP START OFFSET: 1000
Sketch size: 363264
Free size: 2781184
Heap: 48056
Boot Vers: 31
CPU: 160MHz
SDK: 3.0.0-dev(c0f7b44)
Chip ID: 13586851
Flash ID: 1458400
Flash Size: 4194304
Vcc: 65535
```

Edit after update i changed serial speed to 74880 as per comment, here's the output

```
Flashing binary /Binary.bin
Update Success
@ŠZ-nPáM%ÌÍ %Y)Q
    ãoxãÊN
ets Jan  8 2013,rst cause:2, boot mode:(3,6)

load 0x4010f000, len 1384, room 16 
tail 8
chksum 0x2d
csum 0x2d
vffffffff
~ld
```

Comment: The garbage characters are probably from the bootloader outputting information at 74880 bps. Try changing the output speed for Serial and the speed of the terminal program you're using to 74880. You should then see some messages from the bootloader that give the reason for the boot and possibly a stack trace and register dump that can help understand what's going on.

Comment: @JohnRomkey you are right, i have changed the speed and the output has appeared, see edited question for the dump. Thanks so far

Comment: that's really helpful... I've just added an answer that suggests a few possibilities. I hope one of them solves the problem for you. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

`rst cause:2` means that the CPU rebooted because of "External reset or wake-up from Deep-sleep"

If the code you're loading uses deep sleep or if you have anything connected to the ESP8266 reset pin, that would be the first place to look for problems. Possibly the reset line is being unexpectedly held low.

If you're not, the other likely cause is power. The ESP8266 can draw a surprising amount of current at times and may cause a voltage dip if the power supply can't handle it. This can lead to erratic crashes, which it reports as `rst cause: 2` when it restarts.

If you have the equipment to monitor voltage and current after the update, I'd try that - you may see a spike on the current or a dip on the voltage.

If not, you might connect it to a higher current power source like a regulated power supply - try to use at least 3.3V, 500mA - you may need more current depending on what other hardware you have in your circuit.

It's also possible that adding a large capacitor (maybe 470µF or something similar) between VCC and GND might smooth out the power, if that's the problem. I've also seen suggestions of additionally adding a 0.1µF decoupling capacitor across VCC and GND as physically close to the ESP8266 as possible.

One last, different possibility - there's a bug in the ESP8266 which causes OTA updates to fail after a serial firmware update. Issuing a hardware reset after the serial update fixes the problem. I don't think you'd see `rst cause:2` because of this problem, but there's a small chance it's what's causing you grief. You can read more about it at https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/issues/2478

You can find more about reset causes in [ESP8266 Reset Causes and Common Fatal Exception Causes](https://www.espressif.com/sites/default/files/documentation/esp8266_reset_causes_and_common_fatal_exception_causes_en.pdf).

Comment: Thank You John for your input,

i'll start digging and return with some insights.

First i'll check if the MD5 of bins are exactly the same (SPIFFS vs Desktop)

Comment: Found the issue, it happened that from time to time (looking why) the file stored on SPIFFs is corrupted, even though first couple of bytes are ok (magic bytes) the rest is scrambled - checked with MD5. This was causing Upload to work (magic byte OK) but the rest of the binary is random.

Comment: Good call! Glad you found it :)